# Am I generating these facebook opengraph meta tags correctly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Im trying to generate fb opengraph meta tags on my site, so that it can be picked up by the facebook scraper, but scraper isnt picking up my data.

Here's a screenshot of my scraper data
[image: facebook scraper]

And here is the PHP code that I'm inserting into my page to generate the meta tags.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP _ID" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Moodle Deliverable"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Communities Discussion Forum!" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://54.201.93.242/moodle" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.india-forums.com/tellybuzz/images/uploads/D38_Vivek-Oberoi_0.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Moodle Deliverable" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin number" />

</head>
</html>
```

I've used a dummy image link and supplied the rest of the required parameters. But as you can see the scraper says the `og:type` data is missing/

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Isnt your object url http://54.201.93.242/moodle ? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F54.201.93.242%2Fmoodle

Comment: @SahilMittal : Seems to make sense. So are you saying that I was checking against the wrong URL?

Comment: I dont know what url exactly you want  to use. See the answer for more clarifications :)

Comment: @SahilMittal: Thank you for the reply.I have posted followup comments. Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some parameters to the object url, please make sure you change the `og:url` parameter too.

The facebook scraps the og tags from the `og:url` that you mentioned.

Comment: It seems to work with the url you pointed, but when I changed the `og:url` parameter to `http://54.201.93.242/moodle/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=1`, (Im generating these tags to feed in data to a like button), I get the same error as before .. Could you explain how I could fix it?

Comment: Does this link even exists? The facebook cant fetch any data with this url, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2F54.201.93.242%2Fmoodle%2Fmod%2Fforum%2Fdiscuss.php%3Fd%3D1) what it sees.

Comment: I've seen that too. But, the link exists you can check by copy pasting the URL to your browser and logging in as a guest. What I dont understand is why isnt facebook getting data from the page :(

Comment: With login ? Why is it so? Its just an object page make it available to all the users and remove any restrictiins. I cant see the page just like that so how cld facebook fetch the tags from it?

Comment: Okay, if thats the case. Then the following page https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=244216#p1059208, cannot be accessed without login. However the like button is able to fetch the data "Can I add a html block to every forum post?" How does that work ?

Comment: Would it be a problem for you to help me via email/chat, maybe that way I can better explain myself. Otherwise, here works fine too.